# Setting S3 connection pool size in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

I'm using bulk load of `dataFrame.write.parquet(s3Path)` calls on my Spark 2.1.0 cluster which seem to be throwing exceptions "Timeout waiting for connection from pool".

My understanding is that the default connection pool size of 50 isn't enough and that has to be increased (1). What would be the best place to configure the max connection pool size when using the DataFrame's write.parquet call?

(1): https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=81287

Comment: Interested in knowing the answer to this one. I am facing the same issue.